# Meaning of nonprintable characters

Tags: ascii

Sometimes, when I accidentally route nonprintable characters to the console, I get little boxes with 0's, 1's and other things in them.

What is the meaning of these boxes?
What is the meaning of the 0's and 1's?
Why show the characters this way?

[image: Example nonprintable characters]

Comment: It's a way of representing something that there really is no printable character for. @Sneftel summed it up nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Those boxes are the glyphs printed for Unicode characters which are not included in the console font you're using. The numbers indicate the code point for the character. They're shown that way so that there's a visual indication of a missing glyph in the font.